# SQL Syntax error, prepared statement, no details

Tags: java, php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the JDBC in my application to connect to the database via Java, however the results should be the same when it comes to issuing a query.

I'm trying to validate a login, but having some problems, here's my error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

As you can see, it doesn't really tell me much of anything.

For those of you using PHP I wrote a quick conversion using PDO

```
function conversion($connection, $username, $password) {
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `forum_users` WHERE `username`=:name AND `password`= MD5(CONCAT(MD5(salt), MD5(:pass))");
    $statement->bindParam(":name", $username);
    $statement->bindParam(":pass", $password);
    return $statement->execute();
}
```

Here's the code in Java

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet results = null;
try {
    connection = getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(""
            + "SELECT * FROM `"+SQL_DB+"`.`forum_users`"
            + " WHERE `username`=?"
            + " AND `password`= MD5(CONCAT(MD5(salt), MD5(?))");

    statement.setString(1, username);
    statement.setString(2, password);
    results = statement.executeQuery();

    while(results.next()) {
        System.out.println("Login success");
    }
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's worth noting that salt is a column in the database, I'm trying to revamp my login to use a single query, instead of two different ones.

Comment: I'm actually strictly from a Java background, with a little bit of PHP(Whcih is where all of my SQL Experience is from), where are you talking about? Java uses `+` to concatenate, and I read here http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html about using the CONCAT function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typos:

```
" AND `password`= MD5(CONCAT(MD5(salt), MD5(?))")
                     1      2   3    3     4 42
```

Note the mis-match on the brackets. Where's the `)` to close #1? The error message is correct, but since your error occurs at the very end of the query string, there is no "later" text to show as the error context.

Comment: Oh jesus, how could I have re-written this three times with a missing bracket. :facepalm: Thank you, it's all in order now.

Comment: Never assume a prepare succeeds. Always check for failure with DB operations (or ANY operations involving an external resource).